# Why is Navbar Collapse button always showing on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Website </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"> Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="link1.html"> Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="link2.html"> Link2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The button which is supposed to show up only when window is resized to small size, is always showing on the right of the Website name. It is looking ugly in fullscreen, that is, while viewing in computer mode. I want to remove it from showing in high resolution devices. Tell me where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the correct class name for the Bootstrap 4 Navbar is **`navbar-toggler`**, not `navbar-toggle`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Website </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"> Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="link1.html"> Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="link2.html"> Link2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/9uKT2H0EgP

Answer (score -1):

Only use class `navbar-expand-sm` if you want the icon to show up only on narrow viewports. Find an [overview in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbars/). Also you use a wrong class for the hamburger icon: `class="navbar-toggler"`, like 
Zim already said.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Expand at sm</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample03" aria-controls="navbarsExample03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://example.com" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add comments to downvotes – so that answers to the question can be improved.